# Creating single report from multiple excels

Tags: sas

I have three macros below which creates three excel reports with multiple sheets inside.

**12 months**

%metrics(score =y,vintage=y,excel=excel1);

**06 months**

%metrics(score =y,vintage=y,excel=excel2)

**18 months**

%metrics(score =y,vintage=y,excel=excel3)

when i run this SAS it creates three excel sheets with multiple sheets in   winscp location sas/output

I want to know how to create a single excel picking up particular sheets from each three excel and output it into new excel document below these three macros without disturbing it and output  in same winscp location.

Comment: This is definitely possible - could you share the code of the %metrics macro, though? It will be important to see how you are creating the Excel reports, and then I bet we can find a solution. If I had to guess sight-unseen, if you use PROC EXPORT, the 'OUTFILE=filename' should all be the same filename to add sheets to a single xlsx file.

Comment: You need to modify the code that exports to achieve this. If you can actually remove that step and create output data sets, and then export to excel is likely the easiest option.

Comment: I cannot edit the % metrics code. I want to do it below of it not inside.

Comment: A possible option is to wrap some export code _around_ the macro calls, ie turn on ODS EXCEL before the first call, and then close it afterwards. Its feasibility depends on what is exactly happening inside the macros.